# Syntax for np.where replace column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am able to successfully replace Yes\No values with 1\0 using np.where().

However, no matter what syntax I use, I always get one of two SettingWithCopyWarning warnings.  I would like to
know the correct syntax so I can avoid the warning.

I have tried three different ways.  They all work, but they all generate the warning:

```
df['Churn'] = np.where(df['Churn'].values == 'Yes', 1, 0)
df['Churn'] = np.where(df.loc[:, 'Churn'].values == 'Yes', 1, 0)
```

```
C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py:62: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['Churn'] = np.where(df['Churn'].values == 'Yes', 1, 0)
```

```
df.loc[:, 'Churn'] = np.where(df.loc[:, 'Churn'].values == 'Yes', 1, 0)
```

```
C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:966: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

Comment: There is no filtration before your code? If yes, need `copy`

Comment: `df['Churn']==1` should be fine but the current `df` may have been referenced from another df. How did you create the `df`? if  you have performed any filtering from another dataframe to create the current `df` , use a `.copy()` there

Comment: ```@anky```, That was it.  In my code, I filtered out some of the columns one line before. Much obliged.